# .Net/VS Test runner fails when running in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm running C# unit tests targeting .Net Framework 4.6.2.

Things are working fine locally, and it also works fine build and running all tests from VS2019 installed on the build agent.

But when running a build in Azure DevOps, using either hosted or self hosted agent, test step fails even though all tests are successful.

Running `vstest.console.exe` manually from command line, on the build agent, works fine and succeeds. I run this command with the same parameters as done by Azure DevOps.

Error produced from the log (hundreds of them):

> ##[error][xUnit.net 00:00:00.0457701] Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework: Catastrophic failure: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Xunit.DiaSession' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> ##[error]   at Xunit.DiaSession..cctor()
>       ##[error]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       ##[error]   at Xunit.DiaSession..ctor(String assemblyFileName)
>       ##[error]   at Xunit.DiaSessionWrapper..ctor(String assemblyFilename) in C:\projects\xunit\src\xunit.runner.utility\Utility\DiaSessionWrapper_DotNet.cs:line 16
>
> ##[error]   at Xunit.XunitFrontController..ctor(AppDomainSupport appDomainSupport, String assemblyFileName, String configFileName, Boolean shadowCopy, String shadowCopyFolder, ISourceInformationProvider sourceInformationProvider, IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink) in C:\projects\xunit\src\xunit.runner.utility\Frameworks\XunitFrontController.cs:line 64
>
> ##[error]   at Xunit.Runner.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsTestRunner.RunTestsInAssembly(IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle, LoggerHelper logger, TestPlatformContext testPlatformContext, IMessageSinkWithTypes reporterMessageHandler, AssemblyRunInfo runInfo) in C:\projects\xunit\src\xunit.runner.visualstudio\VsTestRunner.cs:line 458

Build summary

> Total tests: 3679
>            Passed: 3675
>           Skipped: 4
>        Total time: 3.4993 Minutes
>       Vstest.console.exe exited with code 1.

At the top of the log, during initialization of test step:

> Multiple versions of same extension found. Selecting the highest version.
>         Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter : 14.0.2505.1
>         xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter : 99.99.99.0
>         xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter : 99.99.99.0

#### Pipeline

```
pool:
  name: Dedicated VS2017
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

steps:
- task: gittools.gitversion.gitversion-task.GitVersion@3
  displayName: GitVersion
  inputs:
    updateAssemblyInfo: true

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.3.0'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore Shamrock.Web'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install Documenta'
  inputs:
    workingDir: src/Documenta/Documenta.Web/ClientApp
    verbose: false
  enabled: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm build Documenta/ClientApp'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: src/Documenta/Documenta.Web/ClientApp
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build'
  enabled: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install Shamrock.Web/Angular'
  inputs:
    workingDir: src/Shamrock.Web/Shamrock.Web/Angular
    verbose: false
  enabled: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm build Shamrock.Web/Angular'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: src/Shamrock.Web/Shamrock.Web/Angular
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build'
  enabled: false

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: src/Shamrock.Web/Shamrock.Web.sln
    msbuildArgs: '/p:SEPrecompilerIncludeRazor=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
    maximumCpuCount: true

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution D365'
  inputs:
    solution: src/Shamrock.D365/Shamrock.D365.sln
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    maximumCpuCount: true
  enabled: false

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution Documenta'
  inputs:
    solution: src/Documenta/Documenta.sln
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    maximumCpuCount: true
  enabled: false

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*tests.dll
     !**\obj\**
     !**\*testadapter.dll
    vsTestVersion: 16.0
    runInParallel: false
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    diagnosticsEnabled: True

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy DACPAC'
  inputs:
    Contents: '**\*.dacpac'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Database Publish Profile'
  inputs:
    Contents: '**\Shamrock.Database.publish.xml'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishSymbols@1
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
  enabled: false
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
```

Comment: are you restoring nuget packages in your pipeline?

Comment: yes, as well as building all projects which works fine.

Comment: can you post your pipeline.yml?

Comment: posted to question

Comment: huh, i was kinda hoping you were running builds and tests in different jobs or stages and only did the nuget restore for the builds. i'm afraid i can't help you with this one but i'm sure there is an azure pipeline expert just around the corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs only when the "Collect advanced diagnostics in case of catastrophic failures" flag is set to `true`.

Make sure that it is off, then it works fine.

[image]

Known issue now fixed: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/763234/e0434352clr-issues.html

---

**Update 7th January, 2020**

This issue showed up again, even though we had aforementioned flag set to false.

The solution we found this time was to add a Tools installer step to the pipeline, and use that from the test step.

Tools installer step in UI

[image]

Using the correct test platform version
[image]

Comment: Very appreciate this solution shared here. You can accept this answer thus others could refer to this solution:-)

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Just added more to this, we had the issue appear again. This time a different solution. Perhaps there's a better way to solve it?

Comment: please note for those using .netcore3.1 this will not work and the yaml is incompatible with .netcore